# How can you say something is good at an evil task?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, adjectives, connotation, descriptive-grammar

I want to say something like:

"Trading goods were excellent carriers of pathogens and contributed to the spread of epidemic diseases."

But I feel like "excellent" and "contributed" have positive connotations, which would make the sentence sound awkward. Can you suggest better words I can use instead?
Thanks!

Comment: The sentence doesn't sound awkward to me.

Comment: I see what you mean, @gyrowriter, particularly the use of "excellent" – "contributed" is perhaps more neutral, but it may be a subjective view. Would this work? "Trading goods were 'extremely efficient' carriers of pathogens and contributed ['added'??] to the spread of epidemic diseases."

Comment: I've seen terms like "excellent" used in such situations; but you might consider something like "Traded goods contributed to economic growth, but were unfortunately also excellent carriers . . .

Comment: Xanne is quite right; the 'unfortunately' (or an equivalent) is necessary if you are going to use 'excellent' here without the undesirable connotation. And it's better just before the 'excellent'. Worthy of an answer. / As Livecache implies, 'contributed' is sufficiently neutral in connotation without special treatment. // '... extremely dangerous' gets the message across.

Answer (score 1):

As Edwin Ashworth  said in the comments above, consider:

> Trading goods were*, unfortunately,* excellent carriers of pathogens and contributed to the spread of epidemic diseases."

The word *contributed* is fine.

Or, better:

> Trading goods were *extremely dangerous* carriers of pathogens and contributed to the spread of epidemic diseases."

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking of deadly as in: 
Trading goods were deadly carriers of pathogens and contributed to the spread of epidemic diseases

Answer (score 0):

“Trading goods were perniciously/disastrously/fatally/tragically efficient/effective carriers of pathogens and facilitated the spread of epidemic diseases.”

Answer (score 0):

### Good/bad is always subjective.

Your question relies on the seemingly contradictory "**good** for transmitting disease" and "transmitting disease is **bad** for us humans".

However, any word that refers to good/bad must also give you a frame of reference. Good/bad **for what**?
Your sentence wouldn't work without this frame of reference. Because if I omit the frame of reference, I've completely changed your sentence:

> Trading goods were excellent.

It just doesn't work.

---

### Examples

> A was running around in a crowd of people, moving in unpredictable patterns. B, who had a sniper rifle aimed at A, managed to shoot A right between the eyes. B is an excellent sniper.

Calling B an excellent sniper is correct here. Because he excels at **sniping**.

Notice how you have no idea whether this was a murder or a justified elimination of an enemy target. This example is completely devoid of any subjective context. The usage of "excellent" would remain correct, **regardless** of whether it's about Lee Harvey Oswald shooting JFK, or a random sniper shooting Hitler.

We can apply this same logic to your example:

> Trading goods were excellent carriers of pathogens and contributed to the spread of epidemic diseases.

So you think "excellent" is wrong to use, because the diseases ended up killing humans. Well, let me turn the tables. I won't touch your sentence, but I'll change the context:

> The aliens continued their siege of Earth. The Sectoids had been bombarding Earth for decades. Billions had already died. We could only convince them to stop bombing us for short periods by offering them valuable goods. **Trading goods were excellent carriers of pathogens and contributed to the spread of epidemic diseases**. In less than three weeks, the Sectoids had lost enough of their people to the epidemic, that they were rendered unable to continue the siege. They soon agreed to our proposed truce.

Would you still agree that "excellent" is the wrong word to use? Your initial argument no longer applies here. The spread of disease benefited humanity.

---

### Simpler examples

> Machine guns are **better** than pistols at killing a crowd of people.

This does not in any way state that killing a crowd of people is a good thing to do. It only states that a machine is better **at killing people** (regardless of whether killing people is good or bad).

> Hitler was a **better** public speaker than Michael Cera.

This does not in any way state that Hitler was a better **person** than Michael Cera. It only states that Hitler was a better **public speaker** than Michael Cera.

> Hitler was an **excellent** public speaker.

Again, this does not state that Hitler was an excellent **person**. It only focuses on his **oratory skills**.

> Trading goods were **excellent** carriers of pathogens and contributed to the spread of epidemic diseases

This does not say "spreading disease is excellent". This says "**if you want to spread disease**, infecting trading goods is an excellent way to infect a large amount of people".

This sentence does not in any way state that "spreading disease" itself is good or bad.

---

### But you are not safe from inference.

Especially if you're talking about culturally sensitive topics, you want to do everything to avoid any wrongful inferences. Even if you never meant to imply that you think "spreading disease is good", it doesn't hurt to avoid the implication if you can.

Edwin Ashworth's comment is a good one:

> Trading goods were, *unfortunately*, excellent carriers of pathogens and contributed to the spread of epidemic diseases."

"unfortunately" reveals your sentiment towards the impact this has had on humanity.

However, notice that it is still correct to use "excellent". You haven't changed the word, you've simply **added** an interjection that confirms you don't think the spread of disease was a good thing for humanity.